# how to delete file inside directory in linux which is created 3 hours ago

Tags: linux, find, ls, rm

how to delete file inside directory in linux which is created within certain time intreval .

actually i am unable to find file inside file for certain time interval ::

Example::

```
[root@XXXXXXXX]# ls -lhrt 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 13:13 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 13:13 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 13:13 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 13:13 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 13:13 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 14:27 6
```

actually i need to delete file which was created within Jul 31 12:00 to Jul 31 14:00 .

Please suggest on same .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create boundary for find to work.

```
touch -t 201507311200 start
touch -t 201507311400 stop
find . -newer start \! -newer stop -delete
```